# How to download image captcha using requests.Session from specific url

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library

Hi everybody I'm trying to get the image captcha in a website to **scrape** it. My problem is that the url to get the image captcha contains a parameter where I can't find where it is from. So I got using parser.xpath but It doesn't work. This is my code:

```
import requests, io, re
from PIL import Image
from lxml import html
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36",
}
session = requests.Session()
login_url = 'https://www.sat.gob.pe/WebSiteV8/popupv2.aspx?t=6'
login_form_res = session.get(login_url, headers=headers)
myhtml = login_form_res.text
evalu = ''
for match in re.finditer(r'(mysession=)(.*?)(")', myhtml):
    evalu = myhtml[match.start():match.end()]
    evalu = evalu.replace("mysession=", "")
    evalu = evalu.replace('"', '')
    print(evalu)

url_infractions = 'https://www.sat.gob.pe/VirtualSAT/modulos/RecordConductor.aspx?mysession=' + evalu
login_form_res = session.get(url_infractions, headers=headers)
myhtml = login_form_res.text
parser = html.fromstring(login_form_res.text)
idPic = parser.xpath('//img[@class="captcha_class"]/@src')
urlPic = "https://www.sat.gob.pe/VirtualSAT" + idPic[0].replace("..","")
print(urlPic)

image_content = session.get(urlPic, headers=headers)
image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
image = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB').content
image.show()
```

As a result I have an exception which says TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Response'. I'm confused. I will really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: `session.get` does not return a string.  It returns a requests `Response` object,.  You just have to fetch the contents from the object.

Comment: Thanks. I understand after the get function, I read using the attribute text and search the html control in the case of the img I found the source src='../controles/JpegImage_VB.aspx?r=43543b9e00854ac0a4ac0f252e53a9b0' but when I tried to access I couldn't.